# Spring nested injections

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a spring-ws web service within which a bank web service is called.

Here is my spring configuration file:

```xml
<bean id="PaymentService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true" />
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>schemas/PaymentServiceOperations.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="PaymentService" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="PaymentService" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints" />
</bean>

<bean id="bankWebService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.stub.PaymentIFBindingSoap" />  
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl"  value="https://bank.com/payment.asmx?WSDL" />
    <property name="namespaceUri"     value="urn:Foo" />
    <property name="serviceName"      value="PaymentIFBinding" />
    <property name="portName"         value="PaymentIFBindingSoap" />
</bean>
```

The first bean in my payment service and the second one is a web service client consuming a financial service provided by my bank.

Now my service interfaces and their implementation:

```
@Configurable
public class BankService implements IBankService {

    @Autowired
    private PaymentIFBindingSoap webService;
}


@Service
public class PaymentService implements IPaymentService {

    @Autowired
    private IBankService bankService;

}
```

And finally my own service (PaymentService) endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class PaymentServiceEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private IPaymentService paymentService;
}
```

Just to make sure everything is clear, note that my endpoint has an instance of "PaymentService" and the PaymentService has an instance of "BankService" inject in itself.

My understanding is that everything should work as planned but when trying to deploy the project to tomcat I get this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'paymentServiceEndpoint': Injection of auto wired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.villaparvaneh.services.IPaymentService com.villaparvaneh.services.endpoints.PaymentServiceEndpoint.paymentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'paymentService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.villaparvaneh.services.saman.IBankService com.villaparvaneh.services.PaymentService.samanService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.villaparvaneh.services.saman.IBankService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My first guess was that it is not possible to have nested injections as I have done here but I couldn't find anything supporting it.

Comment: When your bean is `@Configurable`, Spring won't auto inject it for you, you have to create the instance manually e.g. `IBankService bankService = new BankService();`

Comment: *My first guess was that it is not possible to have nested injections as I have done here but I couldn't find anything supporting it* and you won't find such information because Spring does support *nested injections*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for your response. I was under the impression that Configurable beans will be auto injected as well. As Patrick has answered below, I got it working by changing the Configurable to Service.

Comment: I wonder why you started using `@Configurable` when usually you will annotate your beans using `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` or such...

Comment: I have copied the source code of BankService from one of my previous projects which was working fine and perhaps I forgot to change the annotation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change your annotation on BankService from Configurable to just Service.  The Configurable annotation is used to apply dependency injection to a bean outside of the Spring managed context, like if you did "new BankService()".  I've had poor experience making that work in the past.  If you annotate BankService with the Service annotation, then component scanning will instantiate it and then inject it into PaymentService.